# How can I configure Ditto so that it always pastes the plaintext of the selected clip?

Tags: windows, plaintext, ditto

I found `Text Only Paste` but it doesn't seem to work and anyway likely doesn't apply to clips that aren't the last saved clip:

[image]

I use Ditto with Microsoft Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When pasting the selected entry in Ditto, use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This will paste the selected entry as plain text.